# Python pandas joining two dataframes duplicates rows

Tags: python, pandas

**dfenter**

| User | Date | Enter_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 17:07:55 |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 08:09:37 |

**dfexit**

| User | Date | Exit_Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 22:32:57 |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 12:43:28 |

I want to join these two tables and want to have a table like the below:

| User | Date | Enter_Time | Exit_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 17:07:55 | 22:32:57 |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 08:09:37 | 12:43:28 |

with the code below:

```
merged_df = dfenter.merge(dfexit, on=['User', 'Date'], how='outer')
```

but the result is duplicated:

| User | Date | Enter_Time | Exit_Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 17:07:55 | 22:32:57 |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 17:07:55 | 12:43:28 |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 08:09:37 | 22:32:57 |
| A | 2023-10-09 | 08:09:37 | 12:43:28 |

how can i remove those duplicates; going to use it for larger scaled dataframes.

I tried below code but that's only keeping first column.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(dfenter, dfexit[dfexit.duplicated(subset=['Exit_Time'], keep='first') == False], on=['User', 'Date'])
```

Comment: You can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

Comment: Either use `concat` is the rows are already aligned, or de-duplicate with `cumcount` to merge by user in order of the rows, or indeed `merge_asof` if you need to merge by closest date

Comment: Something like: `pd.merge_asof(dfenter.sort_values('Enter_Time'), dfexit.sort_values('Exit_Time'), left_on='Enter_Time', right_on='Exit_Time', by='User', direction='forward')` (don't forget to convert Date columns as `DatetimeIndex` with `pd.to_datetime` if it's not already the case)